# Why does BeautifulSoup .children contain nameless elements as well as the expected tag(s)

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test="""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>
  <div>
   <b>
    Icon
   </b>
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(test2)
rows = soup.findAll('tr')
for r in rows:
    print(r.name)
    for c in r.children:
        print('>', c.name)
```

### Output

```
tr
> None
> td
> None
```

### Why are there nameless elements in the list of the row's children?

This occurs running Python 3.3.1 64-bit on Windows 8, with `html.parser` (that's Python's built-in one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of `.children` can be [NavigableStrings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) as well as [Tags](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag). In the case of your example, they're the whitespace before and after the `td` element.

This variation on your code hopefully makes it clear:

```
>>> rows = soup.findAll('tr')
>>> for r in rows:
...     print("row:", r.name)
...     for c in r.children:
...         print("---")
...         print(type(c))
...         print(repr(c))
... 
row: tr
---
<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
'\n'
---
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<td>
<div>
<b>
    Icon
   </b>
</div>
</td>
---
<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
'\n'
```

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: I've just discovered [True](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#true), which will allow me to grab all the tags but none of the strings if need be. (Broken edit on the previous comment right before the 5min limit).