# BeautifulSoup .children or .content without whitespace between tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want all children of a tag without the whitespace between the tags. But BeautifulSoups `.contents` and `.children` also returns the whitespace between the tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div id="list">
  <span>1</span>
  <a href="2.html">2</a>
  <a href="3.html">3</a>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(id='list').contents)
```

This prints:

```
['\n', <span>1</span>, '\n', <a href="2.html">2</a>, '\n', <a href="3.html">3</a>, '\n']
```

Same with

```
print(list(soup.find(id='list').children))
```

What I want:

```
[<span>1</span>, <a href="2.html">2</a>, <a href="3.html">3</a>]
```

Is there any way to tell BeautifulSoup to return only the tags and ignore the whitespace?

[The documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) is not very helpful on this topic. The html in the example does not contain any whitespace between tags.

Indeed stripping the html of all whitespace between tags solves my problem:

```
html = """<div id="list"><span>1</span><a href="2.html">2</a><a href="3.html">3</a></div>"""
```

Using this html I get the tags without whitespace between the tags because there is no whitespace between the tags. But I hoped to use BeautifoulSoup so I do not have to mess around in the html source code. I was hoping BeautifulSoup does that for me.

Another workaround might be:

```
print(list(filter(lambda t: t != '\n', soup.find(id='list').contents)))
```

But that seems flaky. Is the whitespace guaranteed to be always exactly `'\n'`?

---

A note to the duplicate marking brigade:

There are many questions asking about BeautifulSoup and whitespace. Most are asking about getting rid of whitespace from the "rendered text".

For example:

[BeautifulSoup - getting rid of paragraph whitespace/line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558075/beautifulsoup-getting-rid-of-paragraph-whitespace-line-breaks)

[Removing new line '\n' from the output of python BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890807/removing-new-line-n-from-the-output-of-python-beautifulsoup)

Both questions want the text without whitespace. I want the tags without whitespace. The solutions there don't apply to my question.

Another example:

[Regular expression for class with whitespaces using Beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824121/regular-expression-for-class-with-whitespaces-using-beautifulsoup)

This question is about whitespace in the class attribute.

Answer (score 3):

BeautifulSoup has [`.find_all(True)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#true) which returns all tags without the whitespace between the tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div id="list">
  <span>1</span>
  <a href="2.html">2</a>
  <a href="3.html">3</a>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(id='list').find_all(True))
```

Prints:

```
[<span>1</span>, <a href="2.html">2</a>, <a href="3.html">3</a>]
```

Combine with [`recursive=False`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument), and you get only the direct children and not children of children.

to demonstrate I added `<b>` to the second child. which would be a grandchild.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div id="list">
  <span>1</span>
  <a href="2.html"><b>2</b></a>
  <a href="3.html">3</a>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(id='list').find_all(True, recursive=False))
```

with `recursive=False` it prints:

```
[<span>1</span>, <a href="2.html"><b>2</b></a>, <a href="3.html">3</a>]
```

with `recursive=True` it prints:

```
[<span>1</span>, <a href="2.html"><b>2</b></a>, <b>2</b>, <a href="3.html">3</a>]
```

---

Trivia: now that I have the solution I found another seemingly unrelated question and answer in StackOverflow where the solution was hidden in a comment:

[Why does BeautifulSoup .children contain nameless elements as well as the expected tag(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284524/why-does-beautifulsoup-children-contain-nameless-elements-as-well-as-the-expect)